# how to set vi options only for current session?

Tags: linux, editor, vi

I often "set number" to see the line numbers, and also "set ic" in Linux vi.

I guess I could set this permanently in .viminfo, but that would affect everyone. Other users might have a different preference.

Is it possible to set them once at the command prompt when I login? Then I wouldn't have to set them every time I open a file.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create file named `.vimrc` in your home directory 
and add your preferred config there.
 
This will effect only in your user.

Example the command below will add set number option permanently only for your user.
 
`echo 'set number' >> ~/.vimrc`
Or jest edit the file using vim
`vim ~/.vimrc`